# Having trouble with a Roblox ScreenGUI script

Tags: loops, lua, scripting, roblox

I have created three buttons (Answer1, Answer2, and Answer3) under ScreenGUI. I have also created a localscript that has the following code.

```
local a1 = script.Parent.Answer1
local a2 = script.Parent.Answer2
local a3 = script.Parent.Answer3
local var=0

for wave = 1, 4 do
for problem = 1, 5 do
        a1.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        var=1
        print (var)
        end)
        a2.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        var=2
        print (var)
        end)
        a3.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
        var=3
        print (var)
        end)
    
    if var==1 then print("Answer 1 is clicked")
    elseif var==2 then print ("Answer 2 is clicked")
    elseif var==3 then print ("Answer 3 is clicked")
    end
    wait(5)
    var=0
    print (var)
    
    end
    print("new wave")
    end
```

However the code is not working as it is intended. I want the code to print which Answer button is clicked but only once each time. But here's the output I am receiving after clicking a button only once.

14:25:06.795  1  -  Client - LocalScript:10

14:25:08.829  0  -  Client - LocalScript:27

14:25:13.178   ▶ 1 (x2)  -  Client - LocalScript:10

14:25:13.846   ▶ 0 (x2)  -  Client - LocalScript:27

14:25:22.028   ▶ 1 (x4)  -  Client - LocalScript:10

14:25:23.878   ▶ 0 (x2)  -  Client - LocalScript:27

14:25:28.879  new wave  -  Client - LocalScript:30

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to increment the loop variables.